# SSRS Report Conditionally Count Rows toward my Sum

Tags: reporting-services

Tried to create some sort of Column in my stored proc and dataset to identify these outlier values but no luck so no code to show. Basically here is what I am trying to do below:

[image]

There will be situations within my row group where I'll have a duplicate row because I am joining multiple tables together. As you can see in the image my second row group I am summing those values. I need some sort of way to only take "myValue" once when there are duplicates, so that "C's" myValue only counts once.

Comment: Can you add a ROW_NUMBER() to the dataset? `,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY RowGroup1 ORDER BY myValue) AS ROW_NUM`. Then you could filter for `ROW_NUM = 1` - `=SUM(IIF(Fields!ROW_NUM.Value = 1, Fields!myValue, 0))`

Comment: Can you put a DISTINCT in your SP to get rid of the dups?